# Error in installing Microsoft Edge on Pop-OS

Tags: pop-os

I was installing Microsoft Edge through official website:
[Microsoft's Edge Download Page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/download?ch=1&form=MA13FJ)

While trying to install in [Eddy](https://github.com/donadigo/eddy) it showed this error:
[image: Error Message]

Can anyone tell me how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge is a Windows based browser based on Chrome/Chromium.  You need to install a Linux version from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download?form=MA13FJ). Since PopOS! is a Debian varient, you need the `.deb` file.

You cannot install a file made for Windows on Linux without some extra work.

Comment: actually, my problem is solved, no need to answer.

Comment: It seems https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/download actually offers a .deb download of Microsoft Edge for Debian. Why anyone would use software by Microsoft, especially on a Linux-based OS is beyond me though...

Comment: How can there be a Linux version if it’s a Windows-only browser? ;-)

Comment: @StephenKitt I'll edit that to say Windows Based...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm working from a Windows machine until my weekend starts, so 
I couldn't determine if the Download Page would auto-detect the filetype based on the OS.

Comment: uhm actually I am using it for the Microsoft rewards.